How can I draw water level in a cylinder like this?
I see this question here and here.  I don't know how to start. I can
Graphics3D[Cylinder[], Boxed -> False]



Are you looking for a solution with constraint "volume==constant"?

@UlrichNeumann Yes.

Edit

To speed up the animation, we fixed the cylinder and moving the HalfSpace to cut the 30% of the cylinder,after that we rotate the graphics3d to view the animation. Now we can useManipulate.

Clear["Global`*"];
reg = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 5}}];
(* reg = Cone[{{0, 0, 5}, {0, 0, -1}}, 1] *)
(* reg= CapsuleShape[{{0,0,0},{0,0,5}},1]; *)
{zmin, zmax} = RegionBounds[reg][[-1]];
original = {0, 0, 0};
vol = .3*Volume[reg];
draw[θ_] := 
  Module[{normal, dist, intersection, tran, x, y, z}, 
   normal = 
    Normalize@
     RotationTransform[-θ, {0, 1, 0}, original]@{0, 0, 1};
   dist = 
    dist /. FindRoot[
      Volume[RegionIntersection[reg, HalfSpace[normal, dist]]] == 
       vol, {dist, 0}, Evaluated -> False];
   intersection = 
    ContourPlot3D[
      normal . {x, y, z} == dist, {x, y, z} ∈ reg, 
      Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> Green, 
      RegionBoundaryStyle -> None][[1]];
   tran = RotationTransform[θ, {0, 1, 0}, original];
   Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Cyan], 
     EdgeForm[], {ClipPlanes -> {0, 0, -1, dist}, 
      GeometricTransformation[reg, tran]}, {Opacity[.2], Orange, 
      ClipPlanes -> {0, 0, 1, -dist}, 
      GeometricTransformation[reg, tran]}, , {Green, 
      GeometricTransformation[intersection, tran]}}, 
    ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", Boxed -> False, 
    Lighting -> "ThreePoint", ViewPoint -> {.1, -1, .1}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 6}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 6}}, 
    ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}]];
Manipulate[draw[θ], {θ, .001, π/2 - .001}]



Test another region  reg = CapsuleShape[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 5}}, 1];
To speed up the animation further more, we use Interpolation to define the function between rotation angle θ and the moving dist.

Clear["Global`*"];
reg = CapsuleShape[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 5}}, 1];
{zmin, zmax} = RegionBounds[reg][[-1]];
original = {0, 0, 0};
vol = .3*Volume[reg];
normal = 
  Normalize@
   RotationTransform[-θ, {0, 1, 0}, original]@{0, 0, 1};
pts = Table[{θ, dist} /. 
    FindRoot[
     Volume[RegionIntersection[reg, HalfSpace[normal, dist]]] == 
      vol, {dist, 0}, Evaluated -> False], {θ, 
    Subdivide[0.001, π/2 - .001, 20]}];
f = Interpolation[pts, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
Plot[f[θ], {θ, 0.001, π/2}, AxesLabel -> {θ, dist}]



Now we can get a smooth Anamate then Manipulate.

draw[θ_] := 
  Module[{normal, dist, intersection, tran, x, y, z}, 
   normal = 
    Normalize@
     RotationTransform[-θ, {0, 1, 0}, original]@{0, 0, 1};
   dist = f[θ];
   intersection = 
    ContourPlot3D[
      normal . {x, y, z} == dist//Evaluate, {x, y, z} ∈ reg, 
      Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> Green, 
      RegionBoundaryStyle -> None][[1]];
   tran = RotationTransform[θ, {0, 1, 0}, original];
   Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Cyan], 
     EdgeForm[], {ClipPlanes -> {0, 0, -1, dist}, 
      GeometricTransformation[reg, tran]}, {Opacity[.2], Orange, 
      ClipPlanes -> {0, 0, 1, -dist}, 
      GeometricTransformation[reg, tran]}, , {Green, 
      GeometricTransformation[intersection, tran]}}, 
    ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", Boxed -> False, 
    Lighting -> "ThreePoint", ViewPoint -> {.1, -1, .1}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 6}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 6}}, 
    ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}]];
Animate[draw[θ], {θ, .001, π/2 - .001}]


Original

Only a starting point since it it too slow to find the level of the water. Here we set the water be the 30% of the cylinder.

For version 14.1, we need to use Evaluated -> False in FindRoot.


Clear["Global`*"];
cylinder = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 5}}];
vol = Volume[cylinder];
water = .3*vol;
draw[t_] := Module[{h, reg},
  reg = TransformedRegion[cylinder, 
    RotationTransform[t, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}]];
  h = h /. 
    FindRoot[
     Volume[RegionIntersection[
        Cuboid[{-100, -100, -100}, {100, 100, h}], reg]] == water, {h,
       0},Evaluated -> False];
  Graphics3D[{{FaceForm[Cyan], EdgeForm[], 
     RegionIntersection[
      BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@
       Cuboid[{-100, -100, -100}, {100, 100, h}], 
      BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[reg, 
       MaxCellMeasure -> .01]]}, {Opacity[.2], reg}}, Boxed -> False, 
   ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", ViewPoint -> {.1, -1, .1}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 6}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 6}}]]
draw[0.8*Pi/2]



Animation

list = Table[draw[c], {c, 0.1, Pi/2, .1}];
Export["test.gif", Join[list, Reverse@list]]



With my computer, level of the water does not smooth.

@minhthien_2016 I have another idea to make faster and smooth,update today.

Beautiful ! I am curious why calculating the volume would be faster than solving equation.

With another edit you should add waves on the surface of water.

You could try something like this:
Manipulate[
  With[
    {cylinder = RotationTransform[angle, {0, 1, 0}][Cylinder[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, .5]]},
    With[
      {water = CSGRegion["Intersection", {cylinder, Cuboid[{-2, -2, -2}, {2, 2, 0}]}]},
      Graphics3D[{water, Opacity[.1], cylinder}, Boxed -> False]]],
  {angle, 0, Pi/2}, 
  SynchronousUpdating -> False]

You can adjust the lighting, opacity, colors, position, etc.
Note
This is purely a visualization strategy. Subsequent comments indicate a desire to impose a constraint on the volume of water. One would need to adjust the z-placement of the cylinder for a given rotation angle to satisfy the constraint.

No new updates, just some errors fixed

I tried to solve the equation for the horizontal plane with mma.

if the cup is cuboid :

Manipulate[Rotate[
  Show[Graphics3D[
    {Opacity[.1], Cuboid[{-1, -1, 0}, {1, 1, 5}]}], 
   RegionPlot3D[{ z <= -k + 2  Sqrt[b k] + k  x}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 
     1}, {z, 0, 5}, ColorFunction -> "Aquamarine"]], -ArcTan[k], {0, 
   1, 0}], {k, 0.1, 3, .1}, {b, {1, 2, 4}}]



but if the cup is cylinder, solve the z=k(x-c0) is difficult ,i need your help ,here is the try.


Clear["`*"]
{k > b, ch = c0 + h/k};
(*Each {k,b} corresponds to a c0*)
(*b is initial water hight*)
Ah = 2  Integrate[Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, ch, 1}, 
    Assumptions -> {h, k, c0} \[Element] Reals && h >= 0 && 
      k >= b > 0 && -1 < c0 < 1];
Aht = Ah[[1]] /. k -> Tan[t];
Aht::usage = "Area of the water truncated by the plane z=h";
V = Integrate[Aht, h, Assumptions -> t > 0];
Vh = (V /. h -> Tan[t]  (1 - c0)) - (V /. h -> 0);
Vh::usage = 
  "Integrating over all the h-slices to yield the volume of water,h\
\[Element][0,k(1-c0)]";
(*Solve[Vh-b \[Pi]==0,c0]*)
v0[t_, b_] := Evaluate[Vh - b   \[Pi]];
v0::usage = 
  "In substitution t, b yields a formula containing only c0,v0==0";

fz[t_, b_] := 
 fz[t, b] = 
  If[Tan[t] <= b, Tan[t]  x + b, 
   Tan[t]  (x - c0) /. NSolve[{v0[t, b] == 0, -1 < c0 < 1}, c0][[1]]]
   
Manipulate[
 Rotate[Show[
   Graphics3D[{Opacity[.1], Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 5}}]}], 
   RegionPlot3D[{x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && z <= Evaluate@fz[t, b]}, {x, -1, 
     1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 0, 5}, ColorFunction -> "Aquamarine"]
   , Boxed -> False], -t, {0, 1, 0}],
 {t, 0, \[Pi]/2, .02}, {b, {1, 2, 4}}]



This site is about programming in Wolfram Language, while your answer uses some completely other software :)

My Mathematica cannot run your syntax-highlighted code. What could be the problem? ;)

@伊斯特万·扎查尔 test were good with version-14.0
