A truncated pyramid with a square base and level water
I see the answer

I tried (see here)
Clear["Global`*"];
h1 = 0;
h2 = 100;
a = 200;
b = 250;
p1 = Pyramid[{{-a, -b, h1}, {-a, b, h1}, {a, b, h1}, {a, -b, h1}, {0, 
     0, a}}];
Region[Style[RegionIntersection[p1, Cuboid[{-a, -b, h1}, {a, b, h2}]],
   Darker@Cyan], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]


Clear["Global`*"];
h1 = 0;
h2 = 100;
n = 4; 
r1 = 60; 
r2 = 30; 
hCylinder = 120;
rCylinder = 70;
p1 = Polygon[
   Table[{r1  Cos[2  Pi  k/n], r1  Sin[2  Pi  k/n], h1}, {k, 0, 
     n - 1}]];
p2 = Polygon[
   Table[{r2  Cos[2  Pi  k/n], r2  Sin[2  Pi  k/n], h2}, {k, 0, 
     n - 1}]];
faces = Table[
   Polygon[{{r1  Cos[2  Pi  k/n], r1  Sin[2  Pi  k/n], 
      h1}, {r2  Cos[2  Pi  k/n], r2  Sin[2  Pi  k/n], 
      h2}, {r2  Cos[2  Pi  (k + 1)/n], r2  Sin[2  Pi  (k + 1)/n], 
      h2}, {r1  Cos[2  Pi  (k + 1)/n], r1  Sin[2  Pi  (k + 1)/n], 
      h1}}], {k, 0, n - 1}];
cylinder = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, hCylinder}}, rCylinder];
water = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], RGBColor[173/255, 216/255, 230/255],
     Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, h2}}, rCylinder]}];
graphic = 
 Show[Graphics3D[{Darker@Cyan, p1, p2, faces}], 
  Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.3], LightBlue, cylinder}], water, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]


Clear["Global`*"];
h1 = 0;
h2 = 100;
n = 4;
r1 = 60;
r2 = 30;
hCylinder = 120;
rCylinder = 70;
steps = 50;

frames = Table[Module[{z1, z2, waterHeight}, z1 = t;
    z2 = h2 + t;
    waterHeight = h2 - t;
    Show[
     Graphics3D[{Darker@Cyan, 
       Polygon[Table[{r1  Cos[2  Pi  k/n], r1  Sin[2  Pi  k/n], 
          z1}, {k, 0, n - 1}]], 
       Polygon[Table[{r2  Cos[2  Pi  k/n], r2  Sin[2  Pi  k/n], 
          z2}, {k, 0, n - 1}]], 
       Table[Polygon[{{r1  Cos[2  Pi  k/n], r1  Sin[2  Pi  k/n], 
           z1}, {r2  Cos[2  Pi  k/n], r2  Sin[2  Pi  k/n], 
           z2}, {r2  Cos[2  Pi  (k + 1)/n], r2  Sin[2  Pi  (k + 1)/n],
            z2}, {r1  Cos[2  Pi  (k + 1)/n], 
           r1  Sin[2  Pi  (k + 1)/n], z1}}], {k, 0, n - 1}]}], 
     Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.3], LightBlue, 
       Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, hCylinder}}, rCylinder]}], 
     Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], RGBColor[173/255, 216/255, 230/255], 
       Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, waterHeight}}, rCylinder]}], 
     BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]], {t, 0, h2, h2/steps}];

Export["pyramid_in_water.gif", frames, "DisplayDurations" -> 0.1]
SystemOpen["pyramid_in_water.gif"];

How can I get the result like here?

You should have put more effort in understanding those answers to your previous question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/306406/1871 (-1)


Illustrate the principles by the picture.



The main equation is (ρSolid and ρWater are the density of the solid and water respectively.

ρSolid = 2000;
ρWater = 1000;
ρWater*
        Volume@Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, d + h}}, r] - ρSolid*
        Volume@reg[d, d + h] == ρWater*
       Volume@Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 80}}, r]

Clear["Global`*"];
r = 40;
a = 20;
b = 25;
reg[h1_, h2_] := 
  RegionIntersection[
   Pyramid[{{-a, -b, h1}, {-a, b, h1}, {a, b, h1}, {a, -b, h1}, {0, 0,
       h1 + 100}}], Cuboid[{-a, -b, h1}, {a, b, h2}]];
ρSolid = 2000;
ρWater = 1000;
sol = Solve[{ρWater*
        Volume@Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, d + h}}, r] - ρSolid*
        Volume@reg[d, d + h] == ρWater*
       Volume@Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 80}}, r], 0 <= h <= 70, 
     0 <= d <= 80}, h][[1, 1]];
dmin = sol[[-1, -1]][[1]];
dmax = sol[[-1, -1]][[-1]];
ani = Manipulate[
  Graphics3D[{reg[d, d + 70] /. d -> dd, {Opacity[.5], Cyan, 
     Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, d + h}}, r] /. sol /. 
      d -> dd}, {Opacity[.5], Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 200}}, r]}},
    Boxed -> False, ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", 
   ViewPoint -> {0, 1, .2}], {dd, dmax - .001, dmin + .001}]


